# Стоит ли использовать bundle.js(то есть соединенный js файл),ни отразится ли это на производительности сайта?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Есть Laravel приложение с множеством js скриптов, знаю что с помощью webpack
 можно соединить эти файлы в одно, но правильно ли это будет с точки зрения производительности (каждая страница нуждается в определенном скрипте а bundle.js будет загружаться для всех) ?

Нужно ли соединять css файлы ?

Имеются  ли правило или соглашения, какие файлы нужно соединять, где лучше этого не делать ?

Нужно ли минифицировать bundle.js ?

Если есть ссылки  буду рад посмотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно слить ту часть js, которая используется на всех страницах, а для уникальных фрагментов использовать `dynamic import`. Этот способ позволит подгружать нужные фрагменты по мере необходимости.

CSS - зависит от объема. Если CSS прям очень много, возможно есть смысл подключать разные для разных страниц. Это касается и js. Тут нужно найти баланс между кешем пользователя и объемом загружаемых данных.

Если это именно приложение, скорее всего пользователь посетит не одну страницу, значит будет использовать кеш. С помощью `dynamic import` можно подгружать фрагменты, которые редко используются (скрытый функционал, который с большой вероятностью не понадобится пользователю, например).

Также, стоит обратить внимание на время загрузки интерфейса. Если оно слишком большое - опять же можно вынести отдельно функционал, который не понадобится сразу.

Подробнее о динамическом импорте в документации [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) и [lazy loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/)

Comment: Нужно ли минифицировать bundle.js ?

Comment: @a_mine Да, это уменьшит размер файла

Comment: Спасибо, ты написал что **Тут нужно найти баланс между кешем пользователя и объемом загружаемых данных.** , если можно доходчиво объясни что ты имел виду ?

Comment: bundle будет загружен только один раз, а затем берется из локального кеша. Суть в том, что если пользователь посетит много страниц на сайте, лучше сразу дать ему весь js, который он сможет использовать на других страницах и при повторном посещении. НО! если js слишком много, это может замедлить первую загрузку, что тоже не хорошо. Вот тут и надо найти золотую середину